# Working with Git and Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, bitbucket

I'm new to bitbucket (free git instead of GitHub), working with it for few days (with SourceTree client).

I'm  working on a project with one more friend, and we share the whole eclipse project directory through the repository.

At the beginning it went pretty well, but now problems started to pop up.

For example, when my friend pulled new updates (without conflicts), his project suddenly became a  real mess. Nothing compiled, the eclipse couldn't find libraries, and once that was fixed eclipse couldn't find some classes (of this libraries, such as ActionBar and more classes of support library and app compat), and later even there was a problem with the resources of the project (eclipse couldn't find R.java ...).

I guess it was a bad idea to share the whole project in the repository.

So what I'm basically asking is, how to work correctly with eclipse projects? What do I need to share and what to ignore? Couldn't find any examples on the internet so I came here.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: just share the actual project. You can all store lib projects in each of your computers. When someone checkout the project just needs to add lib projects to actual project

Comment: @santalu as I said, this causes many problems...

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is only share the code, use this ignore file.

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_
*.jar

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project
/.settings

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Intellij project files
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

lint.xml
```

save it as   ***.gitignore***   in your project directory. And learn a little about [ignore file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to zz-m's answer, Github has a greate collection of .gitignore files, for a lot of different programming languages, tools, frameworks, IDEs, and many more. It's definitely worth it to keep a bookmark of the page for any upcoming projects you might have.

https://github.com/github/gitignore